# List of class objects from list of strings

Tags: java, spring, list

I am getting data from gemfire

```
List<String> objects = restTemplate.getForObject(geodeURL+"/gemfire-api/v1/queries/adhoc?q=SELECT * FROM /region s",List.class);
```

which is like below:

```
[('price':'119','volume':'20000','pe':'0','eps':'4.22','week53low':'92','week53high':'134.4','daylow':'117.2','dayhigh':'119.2','movingav50day':'115','marketcap':'0','time':'2015-11-25 05:13:34.996'), ('price':'112','volume':'20000','pe':'0','eps':'9.22','week53low':'92','week53high':'134.4','daylow':'117.2','dayhigh':'119.2','movingav50day':'115','marketcap':'0','time':'2015-11-25 05:13:34.996'), ('price':'118','volume':'20000','pe':'0','eps':'1.22','week53low':'92','week53high':'134.4','daylow':'117.2','dayhigh':'119.2','movingav50day':'115','marketcap':'0','time':'2015-11-25 05:13:34.996')]
```

This is a list of String I am getting.Currently I have 3 values in list.

I have a pojo class like below:

```
public class StockInfo {

//  @Id 
    @JsonProperty("symbol")
    private String symbol;

    @JsonProperty("price")
    private String price;

    @JsonProperty("volume")
    private String volume;

    @JsonProperty("pe")
    private String pe;

    @JsonProperty("eps")    
    private String eps;

    @JsonProperty("week53low")
    private String week53low;

    @JsonProperty("week53high")
    private String week53high;

    @JsonProperty("daylow")
    private String daylow;

    @JsonProperty("dayhigh")
    private String dayhigh;

    @JsonProperty("movingav50day")
    private String movingav50day;

    @JsonProperty("marketcap")
    private String marketcap;

    @JsonProperty("time")
    private String time;

    private String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
    public void setVolume(String volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
    public String getPe() {
        return pe;
    }
    public void setPe(String pe) {
        this.pe = pe;
    }
    public String getEps() {
        return eps;
    }
    public void setEps(String eps) {
        this.eps = eps;
    }
    public String getWeek53low() {
        return week53low;
    }
    public void setWeek53low(String week53low) {
        this.week53low = week53low;
    }
    public String getWeek53high() {
        return week53high;
    }
    public void setWeek53high(String week53high) {
        this.week53high = week53high;
    }
    public String getDaylow() {
        return daylow;
    }
    public void setDaylow(String daylow) {
        this.daylow = daylow;
    }
    public String getDayhigh() {
        return dayhigh;
    }
    public void setDayhigh(String dayhigh) {
        this.dayhigh = dayhigh;
    }
    public String getMovingav50day() {
        return movingav50day;
    }
    public void setMovingav50day(String movingav50day) {
        this.movingav50day = movingav50day;
    }
    public String getMarketcap() {
        return marketcap;
    }
    public void setMarketcap(String marketcap) {
        this.marketcap = marketcap;
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
```

How do I create a List of `StockInfo` class object from the value I am getting from `restTemplate.getForObject`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just use:

```
List<StockInfo> objects = restTemplate.getForObject(geodeURL+"/gemfire-api/v1/queries/adhoc?q=SELECT * FROM /region s",List.class);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Your rest call returns an array of objects, so you'll need to create an array of `StockInfo`. if you want an individual object you could loop over the array and find the right object.

Comment: This logic doesnt work.Just imagine how will you navigate to each value of object and assign the 'stockinfo' set values

Comment: i'm sorry, I didn't notice that the json you are getting isn't valid. Why do you get this weird representation?

Comment: Have you configured gemfire correctly to return a normal Json value?